# How could the inhabitants of the Matoran Universe be unaware of its nature? [Massive Spoilers]

Tags: artificial-gravity, bionicle

- All the islands inside Mata Nui face towards his front. Yet travel between islands was possible even before he crash-landed on Aqua Magna (for example, Toa Jovann and his team did this). Unless his entire body was filled with water, the oceans would fall to his legs whenever he stood, and he presumably spend a lot of time standing.
- Then again, if he spent a lot of time standing, how could anyone inside him stand? Did the Great beings include a source of artificial gravity in the centre of his back? Wouldn't at least somebody notice the gravity shifts?
- What about the walls, the edges of the robot's shell? Surely someone would have noticed that "the ocean ends here; you can't sail beyond that", or that such walls mapped themselves perfectly in the outline of a human form.
- Above all, what reason was there for the Great Beings not to make the Matoran aware of this? Only the Makuta, and possibly the League of Six Kingdoms, seemed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The oceans didn't fall between parts of Mata Nui's body because all of the connections were tunnels through land.
- As to why the oceans didn't float around in the empty space, e.x.
  Metru Nui, it's assumed that he had some sort of artificial gravity
  generator. After all, he spent a long time before the series proper
  in space, which is notably lacking in gravity.
- They did know that the oceans had an end, they just assumed it was natural. I mean, they noticed never realized that the 'suns' over Metru Nui were Mata Nui's eyes, why would they anthropomorphize any other part of him? I highly doubt that any of them saw enough of it, or mapped with such great detail to tell that it had any particular form. (For bonus points, *we also* knew about most of the bizarre features of the world before we understood his nature, and accepted them as features of the world.)
- The Matoran are aware of a cosmology that's a very good analogy for Mata Nui, but why would it matter if your immune system comprehends you? They understand their role in it, and if Mata Nui is a formless god or a giant robot that you live in, what does that change?

Comment: "All of the connections were tunnels through land"? In _Federation of Fear_, the group specifically travels by ship from island to island.

Comment: I haven't read it, but I imagine that they stay within one general 'region' of Mata Nui's body while traveling on the boats. Does that seem plausible?

Comment: No, they travel from just above Mata Nui's stomach (Stelt) to his upper chest (Zakaz) to his right hand (Tren Krom's island) to his right thigh (Artidax). But if there were some kind of gravity device in his back, that would also explain the oceans' stability.